# apache 'The specified module could not be found. ' error

Tags: apache-2.2, http, mod-wsgi

I got this message when I started the Apache service

---

The Apache service named  reported the following error:

> > > httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 128 of C:/data/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/data/apache/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: The specified module could not be found.     .
> > >
> > > ---

Not sure what went wrong, I do have
"C:/data/apache/modules/mod_wsgi.so"

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I already gave suggestions for this when you asked on the mod_wsgi mailing list. If that answer didn't help or you needed more information, then followup in the mod_wsgi mailing list to your original question rather than asking in a completely different forum again. See:

http://groups.google.com/group/modwsgi/browse_frm/thread/c33b42bc9b86a4df

---

UPDATE 1

For the record, it was determined that issue was that they were using mod_wsgi compiled for Python 2.6 when all they had installed on their system was Python 2.5. The Apache error is misleading and the error about file not found was likely more because required Python DLL couldn't be found and not that mod_wsgi.so file wasn't present.

Answer (score 0):

i had to uninstall both apache 22 and python 265, then install apache 22 then python 265 then add the wsgi_mod.so for ap22py26-3.0, then restart apache for it to work.

Comment: A common solution for the case where you never installed Python for all users the first time around. Because Apache runs as a special service and not as you, if Python is installed only under user account, then Apache will not be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you tried all of the above/below, you could also check if you have the related Visual C++ Redistributables necessary to run both Apache and PHP module for Apache. You'll find out which redistributable you need by checking the description of the download you picked up, or by the name on the module. You'll see a VC followed by a number. Chances are that you need VC 15 or 11.
If that's the case, google VC and the version number, plus the architecture, x86 or x64, and you'll find the Microsoft page to download what you need.
That helped me, hope it helps others.

See you!